# How to append one more class when page loads to div class via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have html code like this :

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseUnapprovedUsers" style="text-decoration:none"><center><b>Waiting User List</b></center></a>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseUnapprovedUsers" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <table class="col-sm-12">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr id="filter_global1">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <td class="col-sm-6"> <b> Use Smart Search :</b>
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="global_filter1" id="global_smart1">
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right" class="col-sm-6"> <b> Search :</b>
                                            <input type="text" class="global_filter1" id="global_filter1">
                                        </td>
                                    </div>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="unapprovedUserDetails" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                                    <thead>
                                    <th><b><center>Full Name</center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center>Username</center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center>Password</center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center>Email</center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center>Contact No</center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center>Role</center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center></center></b></th>
                                    <th><b><center></center></b></th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and javascript function like this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        if(@jsonData.length != 5)
        {
            json = (@Html(jsonData));
            for(i=0; i<json.users.length; i++)
            {
                $('#approvedUserDetails tbody').append("<tr><td>" + json.users[i].fullName + "</td><td>" + json.users[i].userName + "</a></td><td>" + json.users[i].userPassword + "</td><td>" + json.users[i].userEmail + "</td><td>" + json.users[i].userContact + "</td><td>" + json.users[i].userRole + "</td><td><a href='/deleteApprovedUser/" + json.users[i].userName + " ' onclick='temp();return '  class='btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs' style='margin:0px;text-decoration:none'>" + "Delete" + "</a></td></tr>");
            }
```

i need to add one more class in `<div id="collapseApprovedUsers" class="panel-collapse collapse">` when user clicks Delete button which i have created through the  javascript...the class name which i want to add is "in"

how can i do that ???

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#collapseApprovedUsers').addClass('in');
```

Just use the addClass in Jquery.

Comment: i have tried this...but when page loads it will take same class in html code..that is the main problem...

Comment: if i get your problem correctly what you want is you want to keep the Delete state when page refreshed. Ex when user clicks the Delete you want to add new class into that div and in next page refresh you want to have that class in same place. Am i correct.

Comment: exactly that's the main problem... i want that class to be added even after page refresh

Comment: for that you have to keep the state and persist it. in user model try to keep flag(boolean) As IsApproved or somehting. then in next refresh you can check that and add class dyanamically.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want just in javascript:

```
function temp() //called on click of delete button
{
    document.getElementById("collapseApprovedUsers").className += " in";
}
```

Comment: i did this but when pages load it will take same class as per html  code..i want "in" class to be added even after page load also

Comment: You want it on `onclick` and are you posting back the page once you click on delete??

Comment: see when i click on delete page will be refreshed and class will be added of thats fine but it will be removed once page refresh...i want that class to be added even after page load

Comment: then put the above code mentioned in my answer or mentioned in @Iceberg's answer in `document.ready()`?? Isn't that working???

Comment: Did you try like this `$(document).ready(function()
{
       document.getElementById("collapseApprovedUsers").className += " in"; 
or $('#collapseApprovedUsers').addClass('in');
});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to do this around your `temp()` function in the onclick for the delete anchor tag.

You currently have `onclick='temp();return;'`. Try something like `onclick='temp(); $(this).addClass(\'in\');'`. `$(this)` refers to the link tag. You can also use `$(this).parents('td')` or `$(this).parents('tr')` to get the parent `td` or `tr` that the href belongs to. (If you wish to add the class to that instead.

Comment: i did this but when pages load it will take same class as per html code..i want "in" class to be added even after page load also..that is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution...i am using javascript with scala and i'm passing panel id through method parameter and catch it into html page & then using it i'm adding the "in" class...

```
def loadDeleteUser(userName : String) = SubjectPresent(new AccessControlHandler) {
Action { implicit request =>
  databaseDriver.deleteUserFromList(userName, "unapproved")
  Ok(views.html.userDetails("Nephele: User Management", databaseDriver.loadTempAllUsers(), databaseDriver.loadAllUsers(request.session.get("userId").toString) , "collapseUnapprovedUsers", new AccessControlHandler))
}}
```

in last line see i have passed panel id "collapseUnapprovedUsers" and i'm using it in html page with script and add class

```
 $('#@msg').addClass("in");
```

here msg is the string in which i'm fetching that id...that works fine as per my expectation...
thanx to all of you...